# sending different data from database each time you access

Tags: php, android, web-services

The app which i am making is going to run on 8 android devices at a time and when the first device runs app i.e fetches the data from web service it should give it the data of 1st ten fields from the data base.

when any other user wants it should give the data of next 10 fields etc but how can i implement this in php web service when i use Limit $i,10 then i initialize $i=0 in the start of web service and the issue is that whenever any user access the web service the same web service code executes i mean that the $i is again reset to 0 in the start what should i do?

I want the when the webservice first access the database the start 10 fileds data is given to it and even ever it accessess the database again the next 10 fields data is given to it and so on...

this is my php webservice code

```
 $i=0;
  $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users1 where status='failed' OR    status='ready' LIMIT $i,10  ");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
  $json_output[]=$row;   
 echo json_encode($json_output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the android side you could add a `flag` in the url to know what the client requires. For example,

If client needs first 10 fields, he could call

`http://your.url.com/code.php?offset=0`

if he needs the later, he would call

`http://your.url.com/code.php?offset=10`

You could get the value of `offset` in your php file using `$offset = $_GET['offset'];` Then you could run the query desired by the client.

Comment: Actually the client is unaware of this.it should b in backend logic.

Comment: Then how do you understand which device needs what? What do you mean by 'first device' in your question?

Comment: actually it is a marketing campaign type app the android devices have to send the texts in order to decrease the workload app has to run all time on all the 8 devices and get the next data to send to the people but we have no idea as which device will access the database through webservice at which time.

Comment: You cant get two results for the same request bro. Either you should pass some data to identify the desired response of the app (as I explained above) or you should use different URLs for different responses.

Comment: Or if you know which device (model)  needs which output, you could try [this](http://mobiledetect.net/). 

Let me rephrase the question, __you have 8 devices and need one output only for the first device that access your PHP code and another output for next 7 devices.__ Is this what you need?

Comment: No any device which access my PHP code should get data next from which the previous device get but the devices may not access the php code in order .

Comment: K, so each time a device access the php code, you could save the `offset/limit` used, to the database. When next request come just take this value from db,   do the query based on it, update the value of `offset/limit`

Answer (score 0):

You can add limit and offset to request (GET or POST) that sends from android apps.

But if each app does not know about last requested by another app you can store last limit and offset, for example in database. Then on each request restore $i from dbase.